# Keep actor size while zooming

Tags: android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to draw user location indicator (which is an actor) on the map, regardless to the perspective camera field of view, so the size of the actor would be kept constant while zooming.

I have tried following code but with no success:

```
userActorContainer.setScale(camera.fieldOfView/150,camera.fieldOfView/150);
```

Edit 1:
Ok, i have used separate `SpriteBatch` for rendering user location indicator, now the size issue is fixed but as i predicted the position of actor is completely wrong(doesn't fit with background-zoomed map). here is my code:

In constructor:

```
    camera.update();
    firstProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4();
    firstProjectionMatrix.set(camera.combined);
```

In render method:

```
    testBatch.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);
    testBatch.setProjectionMatrix(firstProjectionMatrix);
    testBatch.begin();
    pinsGroup.draw(testBatch, 1);
    testBatch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this actor to another **stage** - then you can perform zooming on the stage with map which will take no effect on your actor

```
    Stage mapStage, actorStage;

    ...

    //render method
    mapStage.handleZoom(); //you zooming handling here
    mapStage.act();
    mapStage.draw();

    actorStage.act();
    actorStage.draw();
```

Notice that you can also use another type of viewport/camera on your actorStage which can be also very helpful

---

If you are not using Scene2D you can also create second camera and set it's **.combined** as projectionMatrix to the spriteBatch before **indicator** rendering or even create new SpriteBatch only for indicator rendering purposes like

```
    SpriteBatch batch, indicatorBatch;

    ...

    //render()
    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    //rendering map etc...
    batch.end();

    indicatorBatch.begin();
    //rendering indicator
    indicatorBatch.end();
```

EDIT - to handle position after zooming the camera you should use [camera project and unproject](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) methods. [You can also read more here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Projection,-viewport,-&-camera).

Comment: But i don't want to use stage!

Comment: so are you using SpriteBatch to render youra actors/map etc?

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini if you don't want to use `Stage`, why are you using `Actor`s?

Comment: It is not mandatory to use actor with stage! i am using actor because it is very well structured and also its action features.

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini It is not mandatory, but `Actor` was made to be used with `Stage`. It is all part of the `Scene2D` scene graph. It allready handles many things for you, so i can't really see a reason for using `Actor` without `Stage`. Could you please tell me your reason for that?